# Change Intellij markup for unresolved

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, highlight

[image]

[image]

I got these error hints in Intellij in my Javascript:

- Unresolved function or method
- Invalid number of arguments

The default error markup is not good for me however. It is just underlined with grey wavy line.

[image]

How can I change that? I looked Color Scheme for General and for Javascript and also Language Defaults, but didn't find anything.

Comment: That's not a "hard" error. IntelliJ can't for sure know if some function will be unresolved when executed or not, that's why it is underline gray instead of red, for example.

Comment: OK, but where can I change the color? My problem is that it's hard to notice for me.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a **weak warning**.

- Menu File -> Settings (or <kbd>CTRL+ALT+S</kbd> (windows))
- Editor -> Color Scheme -> General
- Errors and Warnings -> Weak Warning

[image]

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)